# How to check a value and change other key in JSON with jq?

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

```json
[
    {
        "name": "user1",
        "status": "off"
    },
    {
        "name": "user2",
        "status": "off"
    },
    {
        "name": "user3",
        "status": "on"
    }
]
```

I want to know how I can search a JSON file recursively for the value of `status`, for example, `off`, and get all the `name` values for which the status is `off`.

Also, how can I change the value for `user1` and `user2` to `on`?

I am using `jq` and `bash`.

Comment: you sure can. But why would you do this recursively?

Comment: ITYIM `iteratively`, not `recursively`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To apply an expression to all elements of an array, and get an altered array out, use `map(expression)`.

Extracting all entries that have `off` status:

```bash
$ jq 'map(select(.status == "off"))' file
[
  {
    "name": "user1",
    "status": "off"
  },
  {
    "name": "user2",
    "status": "off"
  }
]
```

Mapping `select(.status == "off")` will alter the array by extracting (selecting) only the elements for which `.status == "off"` is *true*.

Extracting only the decoded names from the above:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map(select(.status == "off"))[].name' file
user1
user2
```

Tucking on `[].name` at the end of the previous expression will first expand the array into a set of individual entries (that's what `[]` does) and then extract the `.name` value from each of those.

You could also have used

```
jq -r 'map(select(.status == "off").name)[]' file
```

... which creates an array of names from which you then extract all elements.

Setting the status to `on` for all entries that have an `off` status:

```bash
$ jq 'map(select(.status == "off").status = "on")' file
[
  {
    "name": "user1",
    "status": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "user2",
    "status": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "user3",
    "status": "on"
  }
]
```

By mapping `select(.status == "off").status = "on"`, we modify our array by setting the status to `on` for any element whose status is `off`.

Setting the status to `on` for entries based on explicit names:

```bash
$ jq 'map(select(.name == "user1" or .name == "user2").status = "on")' file
[
  {
    "name": "user1",
    "status": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "user2",
    "status": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "user3",
    "status": "on"
  }
]
```

The same thing, but don't hard-code the names inside the expression.  Rather, give them as a list at the end of the command line (note that `--args` and the list of names *must* be the last thing on the command line):

```bash
$ jq 'map(select(IN(.name; $ARGS.positional[])).status = "on")' file --args user1 user2
[
  {
    "name": "user1",
    "status": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "user2",
    "status": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "user3",
    "status": "on"
  }
]
```

The list of names given to `--args` is found in the array called `$ARGS.positional`.

The `IN(a; b)` thing returns *true* if `a` appears in the set `b`. We're using `$ARGS.positional[]` as the set to search, which is the set of the names given on the command line.  This means our `select()` here will extract only the elements whose names occur in the list on the command line, and these will have their status set to `on`.

Note that `IN(a; b)` differs from the similarly named `in(a)`, which returns *true* if a given value occurs as a key or index in the object or array `a`.

Setting *all* entries' status to `on`:

```bash
$ jq 'map(.status = "on")' file
[
  {
    "name": "user1",
    "status": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "user2",
    "status": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "user3",
    "status": "on"
  }
]
```

---

Follow-up question in comments:

> And If I want to match like `NOT IN(a, b)`, then? Clearly, I am asking if I pass value like `user1` and it turns off all other than `user1`. How can I do so?

The following uses an explicit `if` statement to change the status to `on` for the given names and to `off` for all others:

```bash
jq '
    map(
        if IN(.name; $ARGS.positional[]) then
            .status = "on"
        else
            .status = "off"
        end
    )' file --args user1
```

Or, in a one-line layout:

```bash
jq 'map(if IN(.name; $ARGS.positional[]) then .status = "on" else .status = "off" end)' file --args user1
```

If I instead interpret the follow-up as *not* wanting to change the status of the given names, no matter what their statuses are, but to change all other statuses to `off`. In that case, we can negate the condition used in a previous variation:

```bash
jq 'map(select(IN(.name; $ARGS.positional[]) | not).status = "off")' file --args user1
```

Note the added `| not` after `IN(...; ...)`.

Of course, you could have used an `if` statement in most of the above variations too, but I like using `select()` when I'm able to.

Comment: And If I want to match like NOT IN(a, b), then?
Clearly, I am asking if I pass value like user1 and it turns off all other than user1.

How can I do so?

Comment: @decipher See added bit at the end.

Comment: Thankyou sir It worked